# different results in IDLE and Windows console

Tags: python, console-application

I write this simple bit of code (Python 3.2 on Win32):

```
def main():
    decision = input('¿Send mail? (y/n): ')
    if decision == "y":
        sender()
        print("Mail sent.")
    else:
        print("Cancelled.")
    input()

def sender():
    print("In sender ... ")
    pass

main()
```

and it works as expected in IDLE, but in the Windows console it surprisingly says 'cancelled' when you choose 'y'.

Now this makes no sense to me, Can you please help me see what's wrong?

Comment: To make it make more sense, print the input to the console before `if` statement. Like this `print("'", decision, "'", sep="")`. It may help.

Comment: Works for me on Python 2.5.4 using decision = raw_input('y/n' )

Comment: Do `print(repr(decision))` it's shorter and shows you exactly what you inputted.

Comment: Could it be that from the windows shell or idle (one but not the other) you are using a character that *looks like* 'y' but isn't? what if you use byte-strings rather than unicode?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read the definition of [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input).  It is not recommended for general user input as it expects syntactically valid Python code and `eval()`s it.